# How can I make JavaScript exceptions more informative?

Tags: javascript, node.js

A very frustrating thing about JavaScript is that if it fails on an external module, it doesn't tell you the line of your code that initiated the path.

For example:

```
Unhandled rejection RequestError: Error: socket hang up
    at new RequestError (/../node_modules/request-promise/lib/errors.js:11:15)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/../node_modules/request-promise/lib/rp.js:60:32)
    at self.callback (/../node_modules/request/request.js:199:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Request.onRequestError (/../node_modules/request/request.js:821:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (http.js:1569:9)
    at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:492:13)
```

In what reality is this stack trace useful? Is there any way to get it to print the last "non node_module" call that resulted in the exception?

Comment: I understand your frustration, but what is your actual question? Btw, the fun thing with callbacks is that they can be initiated from whatever message from an external system. I'm not sure node even knows who/what line actually put the callback there.

Comment: I clarified the question. At some point, execution passes from my code to third party code. Why can't node keep track of that path?

Comment: what if it... doesn't go from your code to third party code in this particular case? Your code may have started the server listening to the requests, but until it triggers a handler you're listening to, it hasn't reached your code.

Comment: Show your code which calls `request-promise`.

Comment: If I knew where that was, I wouldn't be asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

There are several node modules providing an "async stacktrace". They seem to provide a similar functionality to the `Async` checkbox in the Chrome developer tools (under "Sources"). I have never actually worked with any of them, and I don't think they're necessarily meant for production systems, but they may well be useful for a development environment.

A quick google search shows you a number of possible modules (e.g. [async-stacktrace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-stacktrace)).